# Show an Alert for Repeating Visitors except New Visitors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

We keep making changes on one of our old site and we need to show an alert for the users who come back / repeating visitors or the users already visited.

Since we made the changes, browsers show the cache site to them and hence it shows broken to them when they visit back after we have made changes.

So, I want to show an alert to ONLY repeating visitors to clear their browsers cache.

I use cookies to store information, I tried to show cookie based alert to the clients, but again that alert was also visible to new visitors too, which is obviously not required as their browser seeing my site for the first time and would not reload the cache site.

Is there any way, I can popup an alert ONLY to my existing or repeating visitors using jquery / javascript / php?

Comment: Cookie will more then likely work. You logic behind using it must be incorrect. It would be great to see some code...

Comment: You put a counter inside the cookie which counts the number of visits. You can also if you have a database have a field with the number of visits

Comment: You could set a cookie for `new` users

Comment: just put the alert function infront of the Cookie set function :) so new users have no Cookie @ the time u execute the alert

Comment: @Naranca Thanks for your suggestion, I would go with your suggestion.

Comment: @yuri1000 I'm glad I was of some help

Answer (score 0):

That's a really bad idea. As an user I shouldn't have to care about browser caches or even know what they are. Bothering me with an alert isn't good either.

Consider adding a global "cache busting" parameter to all of your asset URLs, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v1">
<script src="script.js?v1"></script>
```

Then all you have to do is change the version number and all your visitor will see the updated assets without having to do anything special.

Comment: I used to do the same thing, but was looking for alert options, thanks anyway

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. In what way is an elaborate new/old visitor detection + an alert telling the user to do something they might not be able to do better?